# Plot latitudes and longitudes from database on Google maps v1

Tags: android, database, geolocation, maps, overlay

I am developing an application where I want to plot latitudes and longitudes from my database on Maps. In my database schema I have three columns:

```
Name | Latitude | Longitude
```

I can retrieve the data from SQLite in an `ArrayList`, but the problem I am facing is how should I go about visualizing these values on a Google Map along with the name of the location as stored in the database? Also, how can I draw a path from the start geopoint to the end geopoint.

Comment: What have you tried? What errors? What did you research?Have you any code to show? Have you sample data to show?  The question may be closed unless you show the effort have you made.

Comment: actually i was able to get my answer by a lot of hammering and cammering anways i would like to post the code here so that others would also benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my code working by creating an itemized overlay class

```
package com.rahul.besttracker;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
Context mContext;

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {

    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}
```

}

I created an instance of this in my main class and every-time i need to add an item to overlay i called the add overlay function. finally i plotted the overlay on map